# How to find if my vector looks at the rectangle in 3D world?

Tags: vector-spaces

I need to check if my vector $v=\{x, y, z\}$ looks at rectangle $r=\{A,B, C, D\}$ in 3D world where $A, B, C, D$ are some 3D points, the rectangle is planar and oriented in parallel with some axis plane always.
If it's important I don't need to find a hit point, only the fact "yes" or "not". But my math level... I know how to make it for two vectors but how to check all body of the rectangle?
I've drawn a sample where my vector looks at the rectangle:
[image: Example]
I hope it will make my question cleaner.
**P.S.** I'm a programmer, not a mathematician if it's possible use simple math language.

Comment: Do you know the coordinates of $A,B,C,D$?  If so, then you could scale $v$ and see if the scaled coordinates are within the coordinates for $A,B,C,D$

Comment: do you know the distance between the vector and the rectangle?

Comment: I know coordinates but I don't know how to find a hit point to check if it's inside. I can't scale vector because I don't know if it will hit or not.

Comment: @zaphodxvii, nope. I have written all that is known about vector and rectangle. I know coordinates only.

Comment: do you know "from where" the vector v starts?

Comment: If the rectangle is parallel with the axis of some plane, then one of the coordinates for the 4 points should be the same, and this would be the distance of the rectangle from the origin.  If the vector originates at the origin, then you can calculate its distance easily.  From this you could determine how much you need to scale the vector by to hit the rectangle.

Comment: @zaphodxvii yeah, I know from the zero of  coordinates.

Comment: @gd1035, seems I got you, thank you very much. I'll try to find the scale.

Comment: You might as well compute the hit point since you’re going to need to make some sort of range checks anyway.

Comment: Are the sides of the rectangle parallel to the coordinate axes? That would also simplify things.

Comment: @amd, yes, it is parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s one way of doing it:

Consider any set of three points $R,S,T$ in our three-dimensional space, which is a vector space, ’cause you said that there’s an origin. You can form the *convex cone* spanned by these three points. Think of it as the part of space swept out by all infinite rays from the origin that fall within (i.e. pass through) the triangle $\triangle RST$. In the language of vectors, it’s all vectors of the form $\lambda R+\mu S+\nu T$ where the coefficients $\lambda,\mu,\nu$ all are nonnegative.

To see whether a vector $V$ is in the convex cone spanned by $R,S,T$, you just use the fact that *as vectors*, they’re a basis of $\Bbb R^3$, and so $V$ is expressible uniquely as $V=\lambda R+\mu S+\nu T$ for some three real numbers. Are they all nonnegative? If so, yes your $V$ is in the convex cone spanned by them. Finding the numbers $\lambda,\mu,\nu$ is a standard exercise in college Linear Algebra, there are several strategies, and I won’t go into that.

In your case, you can check to see whether your $V$ is in the convex cone spanned by $A,B,C$ or the one spanned by $C,D,A$. If one of these (or both), the answer is Yes. If neither, the answer is No.